# TypeScript: How to make a conditional type that returns an array based on the condition?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to type a function that should return an array type, if the input parameter is array type, and a normal parameter otherwise. Here's my attempt:

```js
function test<T extends number|number[]>(a: T):T extends number[] ? string[] : string {
  if (Array.isArray(a)) {
    return ['123', '45']
  }
  return '123'
}
```

I get an error at the return statements: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T extends number[] ? string[] : string'.`

What I'm looking for is the following:

```
const a = test(3) // "a" is string type
const b = test([1,2,3]) // "b" is string[] type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808014/typescript-conditional-return-value-type) Typescript will not infer different return types based on type guards in the function. But you can define multiple function signatures like this:

```
function test(a: number): string;
function test(a: number[]): string[];

function test<T extends number|number[]>(a: T): string | string[]{ 
  if (Array.isArray(a)) {
    return ['123', '45'] 
  }
  let str = '123'
  return str;
}

const a = test(3) //string
const b = test([1,2,3]) //string[]
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=39&pln=1&pc=1#code/AQ4MwVwOwYwFwJYHsrDgUwM5wBQEMAuYKCAWwCN0AnASiOyoSgHMBuAWAChRxp5lUGbPiIkK1ANoBdOsAZNm0jpy49IsRCjRY4AHgAqwdAA8MUACaZiZSlQA%20Y29IB8I4PtnyWwO3LiMWaQBvYFUeYAQwYBwAQSoqPABPADoETDiExPwaGmAgsPDgKnQ4CCpUCQByAEYAJgBmSoAaYEqAFgBWSqlQ7nCAXwLQABsSvypgAF5WusahkGLS8vHlHkG%20kCGYFGxgPCntYXrcgHoTr2YtnbhgcgOhXAlqptqm%20plgM4vpIA)

Also see this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929

Answer (score 3):

Just use [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) your function:

```js
function test(a: number): '123'
function test(a: number[]): string[]
function test<T extends number | number[]>(a: T) {
    if (Array.isArray(a)) {
        return ['123', '45']
    }
    return '123'
}
test(2) // '123'
test([23]) // string[]
```

No need in conditional types.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgIYC5FggC2ARigE4CU%20A5AIwBMAzDQFCiSwLLpZ4HEy5ANoBdaogzkYYAOZj24aPCSoMOfIVIVEAHwHaR4xAG9WiC4hjBEmAILly2AJ4A6GGgdPnOSpVPmlkHkKFAg5EjC9Mw0ADSINAAsAKw0ooEWAL4ZiCFhEQmMLKzZalgM-gD0lYUxrGWYwszG1ZJQ0nJiQA)

Answer (score 0):

Union based return types are currently not supported by typescript but there is a workaround for this kind of problem.

```
function test<T extends number|number[]>(a: T):T extends number[] ? string[] : string {
  if (Array.isArray(a)) {
    return ['123', '45'] as any
  }
  return '123' as any
}
```

See a working example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=53&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgCqJQD1TABM1EwQBbAIxQCcAfCm%20gbQF0A%20ACgEMAuRNgCU-XASKlyVWnQ6IA-Igx0YYAObzBKtesQBvAFCJEMYIm4BBOnV4BPAHQw0123b7DhB4ycR0UUCB0SKwA5ACMAEwAzKEANIihACwArKHsiLxkvGB2PgC%20Pv6BwYlRsZnZuYaFhhAIGJmIALzI6FDc0V4A9N2IAES8-aZkOhrIdgAOKHUNUIjULW0Y3KzhcZFx0ew9ff3Uw87KUKoa8lBTM7NgaHAANigOd3Dq3BfTcOa8wte3D08vKw2exOFzA9zULxKUK8cGhRCCUJgOCZOHCIA).

For more details read [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929) on github