# TypeScript: Conditional return type depending on one of the parameters value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Could somebody help me with this:
I have one of the parameters of enum type and depending on value of the enum I would need to specify the return type.

I was trying something like this, but it didnt work.

For example `parseQueryFilterValue("5", FilterType.Number)` needs to return type of `number | null`

```
export enum FilterType {
  String = 'STRING',
  Number = 'NUMBER',
  StringArray = 'STRING_ARRAY',
  NumberArray = 'NUMBER_ARRAY',
}

type ValueReturnType = {
  [FilterType.String]: string | null
  [FilterType.Number]: number | null
  [FilterType.StringArray]: string[] | null
  [FilterType.NumberArray]: number[] | null
}

function parseQueryFilterValue<T extends FilterType>(
  queryValue: string | string[] | undefined,
  type: T
): ValueReturnType[T] {
  if (!queryValue || typeof queryValue !== 'string') {
    return null
  }
  switch (type) {
    case FilterType.Number:
      return +queryValue
    case FilterType.String:
      return queryValue
    case FilterType.StringArray:
      return queryValue.split('--')
    case FilterType.NumberArray:
      return queryValue.split('--').map((el) => +el)
  }
}

export default parseQueryFilterValue
```

Comment: You can use union type: `type ValueReturnType =  string | number | string[] | number[] | null;`

Comment: @tromgy as I said I need to return conditional type depednig on ValueReturnType map... union type would give me same return type on different FilterType input

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by overloading your function. You'll have to have a union for the implementation signature.

[View in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=50&pln=10&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwGIEsA2NhQAqAnmMHAN4BQccAyjFFogOZwC8cA5HYQEoBJAHIBxLgBoacIWgBGBDtyEBVALIAhAKJ8JUhk1YBBKFACGxRT37CRAfUN8+hgJq7aM1PKjGzFzlxUNbXtHF10AXyoqGFJyAEVkAmIANVMcRMUAZ0ZmNgAfOGyDFgBtAF04AuREABNgADNmYBqo+uqAYxgsCEQ4MFMoTOAEpOw8AlT04AAKAEdEqBS0xIAuOBHFycTxOBiyNbH8IliAOn1cgEo1otzKuBQcHCo2xE7u3v7B4YXiQ4nlmbzJJbYBrDZLKY7PagzC4I4kMgnDxeK73OQKAoPJ4vN49PoDIbgv5QEFzH4gsHkgFQ2IHOEEBHAM45Iwmcyom6scp3LHPDpdPGfQk-YmkoGbAGU4HU3a02HjY6I5EEHzstYoTwEbmY5CPPmvAUfAnfUb0kkA6ZScUQ1brKmQqTQukKxnM4p3Ymu5VQD1m13nVm+X0u07e1XEKgcln5NGan0FTmlCo6uPatGPShSLD1ODTACE1pBlQK0IgOcLALgefY-kTXAumdotCgwBgyCgvV5tEitEyAHcsDB2gALXPQhvUJtwdqmIby+Gh9FQFZSKcttsduAAagrU1X09n5E9pwDLBXU+brfbvV3iX3M7nx8Rp-D54v6+vcFvTMyYBwg+mLgAFogPre9D3nBlFzjV990vDcb3tRITl-f8YEAkD6xOVBTDAaZpmAHAG3YAA+bdCIuKRIkiKhQEgWA4DqepTF1eAhRNRZRQBKJ2h6bI4FsRR2KJM1SS4CRIMVJlvQuIA)

```js
type QueryValue = string | string[] | undefined

function parseQueryFilterValue(queryValue: QueryValue, type: FilterType.String): string | null
function parseQueryFilterValue(queryValue: QueryValue, type: FilterType.Number): number | null
function parseQueryFilterValue(queryValue: QueryValue, type: FilterType.StringArray): string[] | null
function parseQueryFilterValue(queryValue: QueryValue, type: FilterType.NumberArray): number[] | null
function parseQueryFilterValue(
  queryValue: QueryValue,
  type: FilterType.String | FilterType.Number | FilterType.StringArray | FilterType.NumberArray
): string | number | string[] | number[] | null {...}
```

Another example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48808100/17954209