# TypeScript type for a dispatcher in a dictionary

Tags: typescript

I'm currently trying to figure out how to create a typed function that will call the following object based on its key:

```
const commandOrQuery = {
  CREATE_USER_WITH_PASSWORD: CreateUserCommandHandler,
  GET_USERS: GetUsersQueryHandler,
};
```

In which `commandOrQuery` is of the shape: `Record<string, Function>`

I'd like to create a `dispatch` function that will:

```
export const dispatch = ({type, args}) => commandOrQuery[type](args)
```

Where:
`type` is the key of the `commandOrQuery` object.
`args` are the arguments of the `commandOrquery[type]` function.
And `dispatch` returns the type of the object.

Meaning that if I do the following:

```
const result = await dispatch({
  type: "GET_USERS",
  args : { 
    // tenantId is exclusive to "GET_USERS"
    tenantId: string;
  }
});

// result will have the following shape {name: string, id: string}[] which 
// is exclusive to "GET_USERS" and GetUsersQueryHandler
```

I've come very close by defining the types separately, like this:

```
export type Mediator =
  | {
      type: "CREATE_USER_WITH_PASSWORD";
      arg: CreateUserCommand | typeof CreateUserCommandHandler;
    }
  | {
      type: "GET_USERS";
      arg: GetUsersQuery | typeof GetUsersQueryHandler;
    }
  | {
      type: "GET_USER_PROFILE";
      arg: GetUserProfile | typeof GetUserProfileQueryHandler;
    };
```

And defining the dispatch like this:

```
export const dispatch = ({type, args}: Mediator) => commandOrQuery[type](args)
```

But I'm currently lacking the return type. I'd like TypeScript to infer the ReturnType automatically after I provide the `type` in the argument.

Is this even possible?

I've been researching for a couple of hours now:
[TypeScript conditional return value type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808014/typescript-conditional-return-value-type)
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=key+function+argument+return+typescript
[Typescript Key-Value relation preserving Object.entries type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141960/typescript-key-value-relation-preserving-object-entries-type)

**Edit x1**:
Here's the Code Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-http-50m9zk?file=/src/mediator.ts

**Edit x2**:

Let's say we have the following structure:

[image]

```
//file: bounded_contexts/CreateUserWithPasswordCommand.ts 
export type CreateUserCommand = {
  email: string;
  password: string;
};

export async function CreateUserCommandHandler(cmd: CreateUserCommand) {
  console.log("Creating User");
  return true;
}
```

```
// file: bounded_contexts/GetUserProfileQuery.ts
export type GetUserProfileQuery = {
  userId: string;
};

export async function GetUserProfileQueryHandler(query: GetUserProfileQuery) {
  console.log("Searching in db the userId", query.userId);
  return {
    firstName: "Carlos",
    lastName: "Johnson",
    dateOfBirth: new Date()
  };
}
```

```
// file: bounded_contexts/GetUsersQuery.ts
export type GetUsersQuery = {};

export async function GetUsersQueryHandler(q: GetUsersQuery) {
  return {
    users: [
      {
        id: "id-1",
        name: "Julian Perez"
      },
      {
        id: "id-2",
        name: "Adam Smith"
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

```
// file: index.ts
import { dispatch } from "./mediator";

(async () => {
  // Result should be boolean
  const result = await dispatch({
    type: "CREATE_USER_WITH_PASSWORD",
    arg: {
      email: "theemail@mail.com",
      password: "the password"
    }
  });

  // result2 should be { users: {name: string; id: string }[]
  const result2 = await dispatch({
    type: "GET_USERS",
    arg: {}
  });
  // resul3 should be { firstName: string; lastName: string; dateOfBirth: Date}
  const result3 = await dispatch({
    type: "GET_USER_PROFILE",
    arg: {
      userId: "the user Id"
    }
  });
})();
```

```
// file: mediator.ts
import {
  CreateUserCommandHandler,
  CreateUserCommand
} from "./bounded_contexts/CreateUserWithPasswordCommand";
import {
  GetUsersQueryHandler,
  GetUsersQuery
} from "./bounded_contexts/GetUsersQuery";
import {
  GetUserProfileQueryHandler,
  GetUserProfileQuery
} from "./bounded_contexts/GetUserProfileQuery";

const commandsOrQueries = {
  CREATE_USER_WITH_PASSWORD: CreateUserCommandHandler,
  GET_USERS: GetUsersQueryHandler,
  GET_USER_PROFILE: GetUserProfileQueryHandler
};

type Mediator =
  | {
      type: "CREATE_USER_WITH_PASSWORD";
      arg: CreateUserCommand | typeof CreateUserCommandHandler;
    }
  | {
      type: "GET_USERS";
      arg: GetUsersQuery | typeof GetUsersQueryHandler;
    }
  | {
      type: "GET_USER_PROFILE";
      arg: GetUserProfileQuery | typeof GetUserProfileQueryHandler;
    };

export function dispatch({ arg, type }: Mediator) {
  return commandsOrQueries[type](arg as any);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a playground for your code? Frankly, we at Stack Overflow are quite lazy and want to see the askers themselves make the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Hope you understand :)

Comment: It's not *just* laziness. A [mre] makes it so that we're all talking about the same issue.  I can't sit in front of the same computer with OP, so I don't know if I am dealing with their actual problem or just being distracted by something else. For example, what's `CreateUserCommandHandler` and `GetUsersQueryHandler`?  If I can't paste code, as-is, into a standalone IDE and get right to work on the issue, I have to worry about re-creating the issue in the first place.  Which, even if I weren't lazy (which I am, [don't get me started](//youtu.be/GGjcn3Wf5XI)), would be sub-optimal for everyone.

Comment: Awesome! Gimme some mins and I'll post it

Comment: @caTS updated my question, I apologize for not including it earlier.

Comment: Please put your [mre] as plain text in the question itself.  An external link is a good supplement, but it does not suffice by itself.  We can't require people go to another site to see your question.  And I notice that the code in codesandbox differs from your code here; you should have the same info in both places or you run the risk of confusing people.

Comment: The kind of correlation you're looking for is tricky to represent, as described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), but a way of doing it is laid out in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)  That gives [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAQY8m). Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (Note that it makes little sense for you to have a union like `arg: CreateUserCommand | typeof CreateUserCommandHandler;`; how could you call a function with that as the input?)

Comment: @jcalz: OMGGG, that was it! The reason why I had that is because I wanted to have the possibility to have another function that could push to the `commandOrQuery` object additional `{[key: string]: Function}` pairs.

Comment: Well anyways, here's [my two cents](https://tsplay.dev/m3XbEW), using `Extract`.

Comment: @caTS  Thank you so much for the response!!! It's also working wonderfully well!

Comment: So, @JoseA, should I write up an answer using my solution then, ignoring that union thing?

Comment: @jcalz: Yes, please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with

```
const dispatch = ({ type, arg }: Mediator) => commandsOrQueries[type](arg);
```

is that the compiler cannot see the *correlation* between `commandsOrQueries[type]` and `arg`, even though `Mediator` is a [discriminated union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).  This is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

The approach recommended at [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) is to make the function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in a keylike type parameter, and represent the correlation between input and output in terms of [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) on this type parameter.  It's a bit tricky.

It could look like this.  First we should use a dummy variable name to initially assign your `commandsOrQueries`:

```
const _commandsOrQueries = {
  CREATE_USER: CreateUserCommandHandler,
  GET_USERS_QUERY: GetUsersQueryHandler,
  GET_USER_PROFILE: GetUserProfileQueryHandler
};
```

Then we do some type manipulation to represent the operation of this in terms of some mapped types:

```
type CommandsOrQueries = typeof _commandsOrQueries;
type Commands = keyof CommandsOrQueries; // "CREATE_USER" | "GET_...
type InputMap = { [K in Commands]: Parameters<CommandsOrQueries[K]>[0] };
type OutputMap = { [K in Commands]: ReturnType<CommandsOrQueries[K]> };

const commandsOrQueries: { [K in Commands]: 
  (arg: InputMap[K]) => OutputMap[K] } = _commandsOrQueries;
```

So, `commandsOrQueries` has the same value as `_commandsOrQueries`, and it's also of the same type, but now the compiler sees that type as a generic operation on keys `K` in `Commands`.

Now we can define the `Mediator` type as a *distributive object type* as coined in ms/TS#47109:

```
type Mediator<K extends Commands = Commands> = 
  { [P in K]: { type: P, arg: InputMap[P] } }[K]
```

So `Mediator<K>` is generic, and if you specify the type argument you get just the union member you care about.  Like `Mediator<"CREATE_USER">` is `{type: "CREATE_USER", arg: CreateUserCommand}`.  But if you just write `Mediator`, then `K` defaults to `Commands` and you get the original full union:

```
type M = Mediator
/* type M = {
    type: "CREATE_USER";
    arg: CreateUserCommand;
} | {
    type: "GET_USERS_QUERY";
    arg: GetUsersQuery;
} | {
    type: "GET_USER_PROFILE";
    arg: GetUserProfileQuery;
} */
```

And *now* we can define and implement `dispatch`:

```
const dispatch = <K extends Commands>({ type, arg }: Mediator<K>) =>
  commandsOrQueries[type](arg) // okay
// const dispatch: <K extends Commands>({ type, arg }: Mediator<K>) => OutputMap[K]
```

This compiles without error; the compiler can see that `commandsOrQueries[type]` is a function which accepts an `InputMap[K]` and productes an `OutputMap[K]`, and since `arg` is an `InputMap[K]`, the compiler is happy.

Let's test using it:

```
async function test() {

  const result = await dispatch({
    type: "CREATE_USER",
    arg: {
      email: "theemail@mail.com",
      password: "the password"
    }
  });
  // Creating User
  result // boolean

  // result2 should be { users: {name: string; id: string }[]
  const result2 = await dispatch({
    type: "GET_USERS_QUERY",
    arg: {}
  });
  console.log(result2.users.map(x => x.name.toUpperCase()).join("; "));
  // "JULIAN PEREZ; ADAM SMITH" 

}
test();
```

Looks good.  The compiler has the correct types for the results as well.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#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-OEMAASgBRHEAFQX-dQhIXc44yQsGX8thIEycWFhNQXy-Xm7nhP7jVQW4AmtrFlhlmNj1Mz9UL1et-2gTnMsADEhQAGQXF82T1FUVk-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-j7ShEAkRBSSJpgSeQW16ZeaHTpXNcfsus96FuyHdkYAP2HjN0U9YAABZgWCiIdi1OURxCkGQvjdEQxEkaQSEpXZqWhIN6Elu6jH4dIrGDKdvagFunRwU1iHKZupc972UU4MkcD+MgnWgcKPXQMKsTjMVFERUVuHtJRDjpegZY97uWGACfff9wO5dDslw6OlDPt-WO-ofOdH0L8axbChujKb6WTWiWJ4hj2Piif0SwoiEDAC4JqpsoBNSiCvKIdVUBgEgNgMQEB2yBCiAAKxwLwRIAh4yBB-i3H4qAwJChxFGYEW4FwAC1CE4mbDiFahJeJCmXHYBIUByiMhQFwdsQA)

Comment: Jesus Christ. I'm having the feeling of being a child and staring at a badass performing sorcery. I didn't have this feeling in a very long time. I appreciate your taking the time to thoroughly answer the question. I'll check out the links and study them!