# Why does TypeScript not show accurate return type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want the following code to behave as I expected, while not using:

- `as const`
- function overloading (if impossible to achieve with arrow functions)

```
const f = <S extends string>(args: { str?: S }) => {
  return {
    a: args.str || 123,
  };
};
```

```
const { a: a1 } = f({});                // expect a1's type to be 123
const { a: a2 } = f({ str: '' });       // expect a2's type to be 123
const { a: a3 } = f({ str: 'hello' });  // expect a1's type to be 'hello'
```

I expect:

- `a1`'s type to be `123`
- `a2`'s type to be `123`
- `a3`'s type to be `'hello'`

but result is:

- `a1`'s type is `string | number`
- `a2`'s type is `number | ""`
- `a3`'s type is `number | 'hello'`

And isn't TypeScript supposed to automatically infer the expressions where the passed generics are used?

Comment: TS just doesn't do that.. It will not try to infer your return type based on the type parameter. You ca try overloads, or conditional types to make it work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript conditional return value type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808014/typescript-conditional-return-value-type)

Comment: it is one way to go, but it still does not satisfy me. I shall now edit my question to be more precise...

Comment: This seems like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you help us understand what is your usecase?

Comment: As a human, let alone a compiler, I have no way of inferring that `a1`'s type is supposed to be `123` (which is not defined anywhere).

Comment: OMG sorry I forgot to add function declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function ‍‍`f` that you have defined, determines the value of `a` at runtime. Therefore, it is quite natural that typescript compiler, ***which is executed before runtime***, cannot decide what the type of `a` is going to be. So, in order to consider all possibilities, typescript chooses a type that is a **union** of string set and number set values.

I think the concept, can be implemented with conditional types and inference logic in typescript, instead of using a generic function.

You can define a generic type like this and then create other types from it:

```
type F<T> = 
T extends { str: infer R } ? R extends "" ? { a: 123 } : R extends string ? { a: R } : { a: 123 } : { a: 123 };
```

For example, instead of giving the value `{}` to the function `f`, give it as a generic parameter to the type `F`.

```
type Alpha = F<{}>;
```

Now type `Alpha` is `{ a: 123; }` and you can define constants from it.

```
const alpha: Alpha = { a: 123 };
```

The rest of the considered values ​​are the same.

```
type Beta = F<{ str: "hello" }>;
const beta: Beta = { a: "hello" };

type Gamma = F<{ str: "" }>;
const gamma: Gamma = { a: 123 };
```

You can read more about conditional types and inference behavior of conditional types in Typescript [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), or you can watch [Mr. Titian Cernicova Dragomir's tutorial about conditional types in typescript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27fL-rUXrJM).